# Rendering via EJS and Express in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have three things which I render.

```
<h2>Latitude: <%= latitude %></h2>
<h2>Longitude: <%= longitude %></h2>
<h2>Narrative: <%= narrative %></h2>
```

First I would like to just `Latitude` and `Longitude`.

Then I would like to render `Narrative`.

**The first rendering gives me error the `narrative` does not exist.**

Can I somehow skip this error?

Comment: can you also post the `res.render` server side part?